# How to use pass nil to URL in SDWebImage with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sdwebimage

I am using `SDWebImage` function in a `Swift` controller.

```
sd_setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholder completed:(SDWebImageCompletionBlock)completedBlock;
```

in swift it is displaying as

```
let url  = NSURL(string:ventModel.backgroundBlurredURL)
let img = UIImage(named: "")
cell.courseImgView.sd_setImageWithURL(url, placeholderImage: img) { (UIImage img, NSError err, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL imgUrl) -> Void in

    }
```

Now lets say in my model i.e. `ventModel` I cannot get a imageURL i.e. nil. So the app will give a fatal error and crashes.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare backgroundBlurredURL as `optional` like

```
var backgroundBlurredURL: String?
```

and then unwrap your url:

```
if let url  = NSURL(string:ventModel.backgroundBlurredURL) {
   let img = UIImage(named: "")
   cell.courseImgView.sd_setImageWithURL(url, placeholderImage: img) {
       (UIImage img, NSError err, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL imgUrl) -> Void in
            // Do awesome things
       }
}
```

`backgroundBlurredURL` will not be set in case server doesn't send data for it.

**Update:**

If it's in objective C, then you can directly check for `backgroundBlurredURL != nil`

Comment: Thanks Sahil, But my ventModel is in objective c. I cannot set it as optional.

Comment: If it's in objective C, then you can directly check for `backgroundBlurredURL != nil`